# Upgrade Drupal 6 to 7 using Drush 5 in Windows

Tags: drush

Drush 4 has a site-upgrade command for major version upgrades.

Looking at Drush documentation pages, and it looks like the command is not a feature in Drush 5. Is there a replacement or was it removed? I'm using the windows version of drush 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is now available as a separate module: [Drush Site Upgrade](http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup)

> The new home for site-upgrade drush command, which streamlines the major version upgrade process for Drupal.

There's also some reassurance that this will work with the latest version of Drush:

> **IMPORTANT**: Drush Sup 7.x-2.x requires Drush 5 or later.

Comment: The new Drush Site Upgrade has not been tested on Windows.  It still needs work, but is plausibly usable on Linux.  See the README.txt file (http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_sup.git/blob/HEAD:/README.txt) for more info.